# BroadcastReceiver not trigger from ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, navigation-drawer

I try to notify my fragments that the drawer is open or close in order to stop updating the UI. I decided to send a broadcast the the drawer start opening and closing.

However, the receiver in the fragment is never triggered. I don't understand why because I used many times broadcasts.

The main activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
                if (newState == DrawerLayout.STATE_SETTLING) {

                    if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                        // Start opening
                        Log.d(TAG, "start opening");
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction));
                        i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_extra), true);
                        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        // start closing
                        Log.d(TAG, "start closing");
                        Intent i = new Intent();
                        i.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction));
                        i.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_extra), false);
                        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

The fragment :

```
private class DrawerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onreceiver drawer");
            if (intent != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "intetn not null");
                if (intent.getAction().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction))) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "drawer action ok");
                    boolean isOpen = intent.getBooleanExtra(context.getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_extra), false);
                    Log.d(TAG, "isdraweropen in watchfrag : "+isOpen);
                    // If drawer open, stop update UI, stop recording
                    if (isOpen) {
                        updateUI = false;
                    } else {
                        updateUI = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(drawerReceiver, new IntentFilter(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_filter)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(drawerReceiver);
    }


 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        drawerReceiver = new DrawerReceiver();
    }
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: The `IntentFilter`'s action - `getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_filter)` - (likely) doesn't match the action you're setting on the `Intent`s - `getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction)`. Also, you might consider using `LocalBroadcastManager` instead, or some other local event bus implementation.

Comment: @MikeM. Okayyyyyy I'm really stupid ahah ! Thank you. You can post this as answer so I can upvote your post :)
However, I don't understand why the `Log.d(TAG, "onreceiver drawer");` is not displayed... The broadcast can be retrieve by all the android system, only the `if (intent.getAction().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction)))` is supported to detect is the intent is the one i'm looking for. Am I right ? If you could explain why the log is not triggered, it would be awesome !

Comment: I think it's the way it works. So the `(intent.getAction().equals(context.getResources().getString(‌​R.string.DrawerActio‌​n)))` is a little redundant isn't it  ?

Comment: For dynamically register Receivers, yeah, checking the action is a little redundant, because that's the only way the Receiver can be targeted. I'm not sure why you're not seeing that log, though. Is everything else working as expected? Do you have some sort of filter on your logcat that's filtering that out?

Comment: No filter in the logcat and everything works fine ! 
So you say that either a dynamically register receiver or a manifest register receiver with intent-filter do not need to check the Action ? So I can register the receiver without filter and checking the action I guess

Comment: Well, it depends. My statement was incomplete. For a Receiver dynamically registered with only one action, it's redundant. If you register it with more than one action, then you'd want to check it. Statically registered Receiver classes can be targeted with an explicit `Intent` - one that specifies the class name - so there could be other reasons for checking the action in that case. Anyway, still not sure why you aren't getting that one log print. Are you sure you're just not missing it in a bunch of other logs? Do you see the other log prints you currently have there in the `if` block?

Comment: Oh yeah right, so you can regsiter the same receiver with different intent filter ! did not though about that :)
And now that the actions are the same in the register and the onReceive, it works.

Comment: Everything good, then? Cool. I'll put together an answer here in a minute. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help, silly mistake but glad you were here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the action you're using on the `IntentFilter` to register the Receiver:

```
new IntentFilter(getResources().getString(R.string.drawer_filter))
```

does not match the action on the `Intent`s that you're broadcasting:

```
i.setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.DrawerAction))
```

Those action `String`s must be equal for your Receiver to get those broadcasts.

---

Also, you might consider using [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) (available in the v4 support library) for broadcasts local to your app. It uses the same `Intent` and `BroadcastReceiver` setup, but it is much faster than sending broadcasts on a `Context`. Do be sure to both register the Receiver and send the broadcasts on `LocalBroadcastManager`, if you decide to go this route.

Of course, any other event bus implementation would work here, as well, but it might be overkill if you're not using this pattern for anything else in your app. `LocalBroadcastManager` is very lightweight, since it uses components already available in the framework.